# ¿Las preguntas relacionadas a Diseño, Arquitectura y patrones de Desarrollo, son basadas en opiniones?

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas, temática

Tengo ciertas dudas sobre algunos temas:

- Diseño
- Arquitectura
- Patrones de Desarrollo

¿Las preguntas relacionadas a estos punto son basadas en opiniones?
Entonces, ¿las respuestas que citen estos temas son basadas en opiniones?
¿Cómo hacer preguntas o dar respuesta basadas en estos temas relacionados a un código en concreto sin caer en opiniones personales?

**El problema es que toda pregunta que tenga más de una respuesta funcional, puede ser catalogada como Basada en Opiniones.**

Por ejemplo, esta que publiqué: [Revisión de Diseño, código, estructura, patrón en proyecto con mala recepción](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/383755/revisi%C3%B3n-de-dise%C3%B1o-c%C3%B3digo-estructura-patr%C3%B3n-en-proyecto-con-mala-recepci%C3%B3n)

### Si alguien pregunta:

> ¿Cómo recorrer array en PHP (múltiples preguntas derivan de esta)?

puede ser respondida con:

1. uso de `while`.
2. uso de `for`.
3. uso de `foreach`.

Métodos avanzados y situacionales (algunas soportan funciones anónimas):

4. uso de `array_walk`.
5. uso de `array_key_exists`.
6. uso de `array_search`.
7. uso de `array_values`.
8. uso de `array_filter`.
9. uso de `array_map`.
10. uso de `array_reduce`.

**Entonces esta pregunta es basada en opiniones, ya que la opinión del programador puede variar, en como resolverla?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La diferencia radica (y voy a seguir tu ejemplo) en que recorrer un array con un while, es valido, funciona y salvo que alguien objete algun problema de tiempos (esta funcion es mas lenta que otra) es una solucion valida.

Una pregunta que pregunta si un patron u otro es mejor, ya no tiene una respuesta que podamos decir empiricamente correcta. Es mejor o peor por que motivo? porque escribis mas codigo? porque las cosas viajan mas o menos dentro del codigo? porque tus datos estan en esta o aquella capa?

Tal vez uno tenga mas overhead que el otro (y no es algo tan trivial de demostrar en un patron) pero su codigo es mas simple de leer. Entonces, es mejor o peor basados en que?

Entonces esto lleva a una discusion sin sentido. Porque en algo totalmente teorico como un patron (podes hacer sistemas sin ningun patron conocido, y van a funcionar) no hay una respuesta que sea exacta. Vamos a calcular puntos de funcion de un patron para ver cual es mejor o peor?

En cambio, para recorrer un array hay varios metodos, pero son todos comprobables y demostrables en todos sus puntos. Si este tiene mas overhead, se puede medir. Si este inicializa mas punteros, se puede medir. Se puede ver el codigo generado. Y todas las respuesta son validas, y no son basadas en opiniones. O si, si decir a mi me gusta mas este porque se ve mas bonito. Pero mas alla de eso, solucionan el problema.

Y un patron teorico, no va a solucionar el problema, porque es solo un ejemplo de como se podria hacer teoricamente.

Comment: hay preguntas basadas en Diseño, Arquitectura, patrones de Desarrollo que son comprobables, no el tan obvio de cual es mejor o peor? Canonicamente se puede responder: **Que patrón es ?** o 
**cuales son las debilidades de esta Arquitectura/Estructura/patrón de diseño/anti patrón de diseño?** en busca de una revisión de código o refactorizar el código ya existente.

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez para eso hay un sitio especifico en ingles...

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez y tu pregunta sobre eso esta abierta en el sitio y nadie pidio cerrarla.. cual seria la duda en particular?

Comment: Pero por que tengo que ir al sitio en ingles, que mencionas pero no agregas el link, si aquí hay una etiqueta para tocar el tema: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revisi%c3%b3n-de-c%c3%b3digo??

Comment: el trato que le dan a preguntas y respuestas basadas en temas: Diseño, Arquitectura , patrones de Desarrollo.

Comment: incluso tambien hay etiquetas como esta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/patrones-de-dise%c3%b1o y esta otra: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/patrones-de-dise%c3%b1o

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com para revisiones de codigo.. ahi se admien preguntas abiertas.. aca pedimos que se aclare que se quiere mejorar..

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez tene en cuenta que la comunidad entera define los temas a tratar... s iconsideras que una pregunta fue mal cerrada lo podemos discutir

Comment: entonces aunque exista una etiqueta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revisi%c3%b3n-de-c%c3%b3digo Si las primeras 10 personas votan para que se cierre. simplemente se cierra ???

Comment: porque no lo charlamos con mas gente en el [chat]

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez pero si.. se necesitan 5 votos de cierre para cerrar una pregunta...

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez Creo que en muchos de estos casos, queda abierta la puerta para que se ofrezcan respuestas alternativas en las que se sugieren mejoras. El OP acepta la que se acomode a su modo de hacer, o que haya sido posteada y le funcione, al momento de leerla. Pero eso no cierra la puerta a que otros propongan otros enfoques, en todos los casos verificables. **En estos casos no se trata del debate agotador que se trata de evitar con la regla en cuestión**.

Answer (score 2):

Las preguntas "¿Qué es patrón observador?" y "¿Qué es el patrón publicar-suscribir?" no tienen nada de subjetivas. Ambos son patrones de diseño bien documentados y de uso habitual. Las respuestas describirán las propiedades reales de las mencionadas técnicas.

Ahora, lo subjetivo sería preguntar, "¿Cual patrón es el mejor?". Eso si es materia de opiniones, pues la respuesta es "depende ...".

Lo que hay que fijarse son las palabras claves en la pregunta:

- *Qué es, en que consiste, como se usa, donde se usa*. Son preguntas con respuestas objetivas.
- *Qué me recomiendan, qué es mejor*. Son preguntas de opiniones.

Comment: como se usa, es una pregunta abierta me parece que puede tener varias respuestas... incluso canonicas..

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez el matiz es importante. No es lo mismo preguntar _¿Qué es mejor, el chocolate o la vainilla?_ que _¿Cuál es la diferencia entre el chocolate y la vainilla?_ Por ello, mi sugerencia es basar la pregunta en los hechos objetivos para que las respuestas puedan ser así, basadas en hechos: rendimiento, legibilidad, etc.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar'. Y habrá muchas respuestas cubriendo diversos aspectos del chocolate y la vainilla, y serán todas correctas y complementarias.

Comment: al fin y al cabo es juego de palabras, criterio de cada quien y asimilación de la pregunta... aquí me han dicho; _esos temas en las preguntas las reporto y voto para que las cierren, ni siquiera les dedico tiempo ... bla bla bla..._